# Core Plot : plot line not seen when plot value well below zero

Tags: iphone, ios, core-plot

Am drawing few graphs with Core Plot. The issue is this :

**CASE 1** : All plot value are same. Each plot value is > 0. Then no issue as seen below

[image]

**CASE 2** : All plot value are same. Each plot value is < 0. Then the plot line is not seen (it seems to be hidden below the axis line), as seen below

[image]

In both cases, am setting yRange as this:

```
float yRangeLength = (yHigh-yLow)+(unitVariationInY*yRangeExtended);
plotSpace.yRange = [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yLow-unitVariationInY) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat(yRangeLength)];
```

Suggestions please?

Comment: What is `unitVariationInY`? If negative, the data will be below the plot range, assuming that `yLow` is the minimum data value.

Comment: @EricSkroch , unitVariationInY is 0 in these cases

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added a condition which says that if unitVariationInY is 0 (which is what was the case in the above scenario where the issue was present), I changed it to a non-zero +ve value and it works!